# CSS tooltips won't stretch, can only have fixed width

Tags: html, css, position, tooltip

I have tooltips whose content can range from very long to very short. I don't want to have 3 words' worth of content and have a huge tooltip, but I also don't want 20 words and have it all scrunched up on multiple lines. With this current setup, it stays stuck at the minimum width regardless.

The CSS:

```
.tooltip {
  outline: none; position: relative;
  min-width: 75px; max-width: 255px;
}

.tooltip .tool-content {
  opacity: 0; visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}

.tooltip:hover .tool-content {
  background: #999; border: 1px solid #555; color: #000000;

  /* general styling */
  position: absolute; left: 1.3em; top: 2.6em; z-index: 99;
  visibility: visible; opacity: 1;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<div class='tooltip'>
(content to hover)
    <span class='tool-content'>
        (tooltip content)
    </span>
</div>
```

What troubles me is that I can take off position: relative and it works as intended! Yet I can find no work around, and relative positioning is key (or appears to be?) to having CSS hovers.

Comment: I guess you mean, when you don't use `position:absolute;` on the tooltip it won't work? That's because the size of the tooltip can't exceed the size of its container, when positioned relatively without setting an explicit width.

Comment: Looks fine to me in IE9 and Chrome (not sure how it behaves in all browsers/circumstances): http://jsfiddle.net/EE3Ys/

Comment: Indeed I am embarrassed to say it did work; for this example, I stripped out what I thought wasn't needed. The .tooltip was attached to a div that had a width set and it was overwriting the tooltip's width. Moving it to a child of that div solved it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
.tooltip {
  outline: none;
  position: relative;
  width: 75px;
  min-width: 75px;
  max-width: 255px;
}

.tooltip .tool-content {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

You can remove `span` and replace it with a block level element (like `div` with style `display:block`)

Answer (score 32):

maybe......

```
width: max-content; 
max-width: 200px; /* (as much as you want) */
```

Comment: This really works and doesn't have any limitations of the other solutions on this page! https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_width_max-content

Comment: Why hasn't this answer got more votes? I'm assuming it's new? It worked like a magic for me, although mine might be very simple case.

Comment: easiest and most consistent solution by far, thank you

Comment: This isn't dynamic and it's not a great solution if you have to handle responsive design.

Comment: tnx. This code works very well

Answer (score 16):

Two things, 1st the example you saw has `width: 120px;` which control the width. change it to whatever you need to be fixed.

Or if you don't want to fix the width, just add `white-space: nowrap;` so the text display in one line without wrap.

UPDATED: you could use `display: block;` so the tooltip get max width up to the parent width, see example below

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
  .tooltip {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
  }
  
  .tooltip .tooltiptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    /* Position the tooltip */
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  
  .tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
  }
</style>

<body style="text-align:center;">

  <p>Move the mouse over the text below:</p>

  <div class="tooltip">Hover over me
    <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
  </div>
  <br><br>
  <div class="tooltip">Hover over me Hover over me
    <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text very very very very very very very very long</span>
  </div>
  <br><br>
  <div class="tooltip">Hover over me Hover over me 3
    <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text very very very very very very very very long very very very very very very very very long very very very very very very very very long very very very very very very very very long very very very very very very very very long very very very very very very very very long very very very very very very very very long</span>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Option 2, use bootstrap tooltip with customized hover effect, make it very easy:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var originalLeave = $.fn.tooltip.Constructor.prototype.leave;
  $.fn.tooltip.Constructor.prototype.leave = function(obj) {
    var self = obj instanceof this.constructor ?
      obj : $(obj.currentTarget)[this.type](this.getDelegateOptions()).data('bs.' + this.type)
    var container, timeout;

    originalLeave.call(this, obj);

    if (obj.currentTarget) {
      container = $(obj.currentTarget).siblings('.tooltip')
      timeout = self.timeout;
      container.one('mouseenter', function() {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        container.one('mouseleave', function() {
          $.fn.tooltip.Constructor.prototype.leave.call(self, self);
        });
      })
    }
  };

  //init all tooltip
  $('body').tooltip({
    selector: '[data-toggle=tooltip]',
    trigger: 'hover',
    delay: {
      hide: 50
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.centered {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.tooltip-inner {
  max-width: 500px !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<ul class="list-inline centered">
  <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Hooray!">Left</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.">Right</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Well, I may have spoken slightly too soon. This does dynamically scale the tooltip text, but if the text is longer than the tooltip (i.e. what you hover over), the tooltip text pop-up is no longer centered over the tooltip (as in the "Bottom" example on the page I linked).

Comment: Yeah...and since some of my tooltips are literally paragraphs, nowrap ain't gonna fly. It just cuts them off. It needs to dynamically scale the width up to the max-width, then wrap the text to the next line(s). Sorry, I know "pure programming questions" are apparently off-topic, but I have no clue whatsoever how to implement any of this. It's just not working.

Comment: I can't limit the length of the tooltip to the parent width, it's almost always going to be longer.

Comment: I've been playing with white-space settings. What I want is what it SOUNDS like pre-wrap is supposed to do (wrap when necessary and on line breaks), except it doesn't work that way in practice. It still wraps text at like 80px even when the max-width is 500px.

Comment: @L.Blissett then I would suggest use bootstrap tooltip, if you check the updated code (option 2) very easy to use, and you can set the max-width by css.

Comment: Thanks, this is MOSTLY working. Any idea if I can make the tooltip stay open as long as my mouse cursor is on it?

Comment: @L.Blissett ok use bootstrap popover will make it easy, check the updated option 2 =D

Comment: Yeah, I found that same solution. I'm using it literally verbatim in my code and it's not working at all. And is it possible to do something similar with a tooltip instead of a popover? I don't want to spend a bunch of time redesigning a popover to look just like a tooltip. Feels like I'm going in circles here, fixing one problem introduces two new ones.

Comment: I really appreciate your help but I'm at my wits end here. Nothing works. Everything is insanely complicated for what seems like should be the default damn behavior.

Comment: Looks like mouseover events simply are not working in my code. Bizarre and frustrating. Awful day.

Comment: Yes. It seems that mouseover is not working because the span in question does not exist at DOM load. It's an AJAX app. At this point I'm just stuck. Two different options that each do half of what I want, and it's literally impossible to resolve. Even more frustrating since, again, this just seems like absolutely common sense behavior to me. I think the only thing I can try now is to edit tooltip.js to make it work correctly.

Comment: To anyone still reading, I will literally pay you $20 if you can show me how to make Bootstrap tooltips (NOT popovers) behave the way I describe above.

Answer (score 3):

If having a single-line tooltip is fine for your needs, you could also just add
`white-space: pre` to the `.tool-content`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a `max-width` and put in `word-break: break-all` or `word-wrap: break-word` on your css on the element or in its inner div.