# CSS3: Tooltip Max Width with Word Wrap

Tags: html, css

Trying to apply max-width in case of text wrap for tooltip in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Seenu/yjYW4/), but it applies the default width.

HTML:

```
<div id="container" style="margin: 167px 135px 0px 0px; height: 400px">
<a class="tooltip" tip="television">content1</a>
<a class="tooltip" tip="By noon yesterday, news television screens were filled with visuals of a Delhi we have been familiarized with over the past year.">content2</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.tooltip{
display: inline;
position: relative;
white-space: pre-wrap;       /* css-3 */
margin: 20px 20px 20px 20px; 
height: 30px;  
width: 50px
 }

.tooltip:hover:after{
background: #8FBC8F;
border-radius: 5px;
bottom: 26px;
color: #000;
content: attr(tip);
left: 20%;
padding: 5px 15px;
position: absolute;
z-index: 98;
width:auto;
min-width:50px;
max-width:500px;
}

.tooltip:hover:before{
border: solid;
border-color: #8FBC8F transparent;
border-width: 6px 6px 0 6px;
bottom: 20px;
content: "";
left: 50%;
position: absolute;
z-index: 99;
}
```

when the text in the tooltip is getting word wrapped, width should go up to some max width instead of the default width so that it is convenient for reading.

this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Seenu/yjYW4/7/) works when i put display: inline-table; like below

```
.tooltip:hover:after{
 :
 :
display: inline-table;
}
```

But it works only in Chrome and not on IE

Comment: haven't you seen the fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/Seenu/yjYW4/ when the text in the tooltip is getting word wrapped, width should go up to some max width instead of the default width so that it is convenient for reading.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `display:inline` and `max-width` and for some browser use word wrap.There is a good tutorial to create css3 tooltip [create css3 tooltip](http://talkerscode.com/webtricks/create-simple-tooltip-using-css3.php).

Here's some code from that tutorial:

```
.tooltip
{
 display: inline;
 position: relative;
}
.tooltip:hover:after
{
 background: #333;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
 border-radius: 5px;
 bottom: 26px;
 color: #fff;
 content: attr(title);
 left: 20%;
 padding: 5px 15px;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 98;
 width: 220px;
 max-width: 220px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Stumbled upon the same problem, and after some fiddling found following workaround for my case: you have to wrap tooltip content in another element, which will have your expected max-width for the tooltip in width, and positioned absolute. Then wrapped content will use this as baseline max width while wrapping text.

Verified that it works in latest public IE/Edge/Chrome/FF at the time of writing

Codepen: https://codepen.io/jfhs/pen/LzbwgJ

In code:

```
<div class="tooltip">
 <div class="tooltip-content-wrapper">
  <div class="tooltip-content">Long long text</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
}

.tooltip-content-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px; /* THIS is your max-width for tooltip */
  visibility: hidden;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltip-content-wrapper {
  visibility: visible;
}

.tooltip-content {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Yes this works but it has nothing to do with pseudo elements.

Answer (score 0):

Please change your CSS min-width and max-width like below:

```
.tooltip:hover:after{
    background: #8FBC8F;
    border-radius: 5px;
    bottom: 26px;
    color: #000;
    content: attr(tip);
    left: 20%;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 98;
    width:auto;
    min-width:500px; /* I have changed here */
    max-width:500px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this old question as I too was looking to see if it was possible to get `min-width` and `max-width` to work without having to add JavaScript or extra elements (as I was sourcing the tooltip text from an attribute). It turns out that changing `width: auto;` to `width: max-content;` in your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Seenu/yjYW4/7/) does the trick (as suggested at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62853552). Screenshot:

[image]